# How to get the dropped link from internet browser to my application?

Tags: windows, delphi, hyperlink, browser

Alright my application has a window. I want to do something when a link from my Internet Browser (e.g. Mozilla Firefox) is drag&dropped on the window of my application. What should I do? It's been a while that I've been searching, but I couldn't find any answer.

Comment: this could require one implementation per browser.

Comment: @11684: I don't think so. I have tested this with Firefox. Links can be even dropped on start menu which creates a shortcut; therefore, I think this has to have a standard method.

Comment: Just skim through the `Drag and Drop Component Suite`, I think that handles the compatibility. Plus, the start menu is _not_ written in Delphi, I think.

Comment: @11684: Who said start menu is written in Delphi? What I meant is, this must have a standard thing in Windows and it has.

Comment: Yes, Windows must have a standard thing, I agree, but not necessarily in Delphi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way will be to use [Drag and Drop Component Suite](http://melander.dk/delphi/dragdrop/).

Comment: This is great that it is also open-source :)